# Why do I get version error while running pig script?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, bigdata, oozie

While running pig script I am getting JobContext error like:

> org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop20.PigJobControl - falling back
>   to default JobControl (not using hadoop 0.20 ?)

Comment: QueryOptimizer - MR plan size before optimization: 1
2015-11-17 11:40:18,992 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer - MR plan size after optimization: 1
2015-11-17 11:40:19,306 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy - Connecting to ResourceManager at localhost/127.0.0.1:8032
2015-11-17 11:40:19,957 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop20.PigJobControl - falling back to default JobControl (not using hadoop 0.20 ?)

Comment: Where is the error?  What you've posted is a warning.

Comment: I guess it is some type of error since he may not be using Hadoop 0.20